# Discord bot sent DM to people who have a specific role

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to make a discord bot who send message to people who react with an emoji (already done) and send DM to my moderator (people who have the role). I tried some methods but no one was working can someone help me ?

```
const Discord = require ("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
const config = require("./config.json")

let prefix = "$"

client.login(config.token)


client.on("raw", event =>{
    console.log(event)
    const eventName = event.t
    if(eventName === "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD"){
        if(event.d.message_id === "597553415999979551"){
            var reactionChannel = client.channels.get(event.d.channel_id)
            if(reactionChannel.messages.has(event.d.message_id)){
                return
            }
            else{
                reactionChannel.fetchMessage(event.d.message_id)
                .then(msg => {
                    var msgReaction = msg.reactions.get(event.d.emoji.name + ":" + event.d.emoji.id)
                    var user = client.users.get(event.d.user_id)
                    client.emit("messageReactionAdd", msgReaction, user)
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
            }

        }
    }


})

client.on("messageReactionAdd", (messageReaction, user, message) => {
    console.log(user.username + " a réagis")
    var member = messageReaction.message.guild.members.find(member => member.id === user.id)
    if(member){
        member.createDM().then(function (channel) {
            channel.send("Un modérateur vous prendra en charge dans les plus bref délais")
        })
        messageReaction.remove(member)

    }
})
```

It's the part which send a message to the guy who react